# Can I add two options field in composite address field in Dynamics CRM 2016?

Tags: javascript, bit-fields, accounts, dynamics-crm-2016

I've a quick client request to customize composite address field on accounts form. The requirement is to add two options field namely, `Billing`with options `yes` and `no`. I can hide/show and even change the label of fields on fly-out of composite field but how can I add a new field in composite field.

I would like to seek your thoughts on it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, adding attributes to composite fields is not possible.  You'll have to display the additional fields separately on the form.  You could also write a custom web resource what would mimic the composite flyout functionality, but it would be quite a bit of work.